# How to add login api using nsjsonserilization.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsurlconnection

I have a api like this http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/users/app/login and want to fire this api on login button click. I need to match email and password.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
   name = [NSMutableArray new];

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
   NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/users/app/login"];
   NSURLRequest *request= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   didReceiveResponse:  (nonnull NSURLResponse *)response     {
  data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"Did receive response"); 
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData   *)theta {
  [data appendData:thedata];
   NSLog(@"daata");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection  *)connection {
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
  name= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError   *)error      {
     UIAlertView *errorview= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"       message:@"The download could not complete please make sure you're connected to internet" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorview show];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender    {


 }
```

Comment: You read the NSJSONSerialization documentation and go from there.

Comment: I parse it already using NSJSONSerialization but how will match text field data with api.?

Comment: can u show ur code

Comment: yes karthik sir i edit my question again.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sir how will i get response from this api?

Comment: your request type is `GET` or `POST`

Comment: request type is POST

Comment: ok final question can you show ur parameetr

Comment: yes sir "email": user_name,
        "password": password,
        "deviceToken":'testdata'

Comment: should i wait karthik sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110125/discussion-between-sandeep-tomar-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Hello sir Please give some idea, i am stuck here from last few hours

Comment: @sandeeptomar - wait for 2 minutes , in here net is probelm

Comment: ok sir no problem i am waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**

add the following details in your .plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
 </dict>
```

**step-2**

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender    {




NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/users/app/login"]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
//  email": user_name, "password": password, "deviceToken":'testdata
NSString * params =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&deviceToken=testdata",yourEmailtextfield.text,yourpasswordtextfield.text];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody =[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  // ...
                                   NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                  if(error == nil)
                                  {
                                      // use NSJSON Serlizeitaion and serlize your value
                                      NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                  }
                              }];

[task resume];

}
```

for additional information see this [tutorial](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/)

Comment: Thanks for your response my bro

Comment: so i will place this code in viewdidload method right?

Comment: or login button action method?

Comment: @NSString * params =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=Ravi@xxx.com&password=xxxx&deviceToken=testdata"]; -- in this line add your email and password bro

Comment: thanks sir but there is one problem, it is static but i need to create email and password dynamically

Comment: user name and password can be different for every user

Comment: In case if i change user and password than it will give me error sir

Comment: @sandeeptomar - I agree bro , can u update ur question once , it is easy to solve

Comment: @sandeeptomar - add this line   NSString * params =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&deviceToken=testdata",yourEmailtextfield.text,yourpasswordtextfield.text]; and check

Comment: Thanks karthik bro you always help me, its working now. i think some one change credential that why it gives me wrong password but it work now thanks you bro

Comment: sir one more question i have, how will i match the textfield value with api values. for example if email and password will not match than i will able to show alert view

Comment: @sandeeptomar - simple bro, when ever u do the serlization on that place check , success or failure , if it is failure show the alert else do the continue work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110328/discussion-between-sandeep-tomar-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: sir i entered correct email and password but i still get wrong password from service

Comment: is mean issue not in ur side check once in backend side

Comment: we used email id is a@b.c and password is qwert.

Comment: yes sir but everyone else use same credentials and its worked but in my case i get wrong password from service

Comment: what the response u get bro from back end side , can u show the console report

Comment: 2016-04-27 10:31:42.954 Juststart[1603:23887] params email=a@b.c&password=qwert&deviceToken=testdata
2016-04-27 10:31:43.522 Juststart[1603:24061] Response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7c852c20> { URL: http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/users/app/login } { status code: 400, headers 2016-04-27 10:31:43.522 Juststart[1603:24061] Data = {"code":400,"status":0,"acType":"","user":null,"message":"Oops! Wrong password."}